# Streaming Replication fails after COPY a large CSV into postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, wal

I have setup a postgreSQL cluster in Streaming Replication with one master and two slaves.

I created some databases and I saw that replicated to the slaves. 
Then I performed a COPY command to import a large dataset (3GB) on master.  When COPY command finished with message: `COPY 43928933` I observe a strange behaviour. The data imported from csv are not replicated to the slaves and the streaming replication does not work anymore. I create a database on master node which did not replicated to the slaves.

I see the logs on one slave with

```
tail -f 100 /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.4-main.log
```

and I see this:

> 2019-06-27 14:12:48.919 UTC [13099] LOG:  started streaming WAL from
>   primary at 0/20000000 on timeline 1 2019-06-27 14:12:48.919 UTC
>   [13099] FATAL:  could not receive data from WAL stream: ERROR: 
>   requested WAL segment 000000010000000000000020 has already been
>   removed
>
> 2019-06-27 14:12:53.931 UTC [13104] LOG:  started streaming
>    WAL from primary at 0/20000000 on timeline 1 2019-06-27 14:12:53.931
>    UTC [13104] FATAL:  could not receive data from WAL stream: ERROR: 
>    requested WAL segment 000000010000000000000020 has already been
>    removed
>
> 2019-06-27 14:12:58.943 UTC [13113] LOG:  started streaming  WAL from
>   primary at 0/20000000 on timeline 1 2019-06-27 14:12:58.943  UTC
>   [13113] FATAL:  could not receive data from WAL stream: ERROR:
>   requested WAL segment 000000010000000000000020 has already been 
>   removed

Does anyone know how to fix this? I do not understand this behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For postgresql 9.4, you need to increase wal_keep_segments or use [replication slots](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/warm-standby.html#STREAMING-REPLICATION-SLOTS) so the primary doesn't overwrite WALs before the slaves can receive them.

Comment: Before the COPY command I have to increase the wal_keep_segments? I tried to do this now but the error is the same

Comment: Yes, you will need to increase it sufficiently so that the WAL segments won't be overwritten.  It's a bit of a guessing game, which is why it's preferred to use replication slots.

Comment: I increased the wal_keep_segments but I have the same problem. Do you know how to fix without recreating the cluster?

Comment: No, your replicas are now out of date and will need to be rebuilt before they can start streaming data again (unless you also have a WAL archive).  Use replication slots this time to prevent this from happening again.